# Maximum length of identifier in name mangling

Tags: delphi, name-mangling

Whilst going through `dbkdebugxxx.bpl` I was trying to unmangle the following exported name:

`@Exceptionnotificationdialog@ReportExceptionNotification$qqrx20System@UnicodeString83System@%Set$56Exceptionnotificationdialog@TExceptionNotificationOptiont1$i0$t1$i2$%r83System@%Set$56Exceptionnotificationdialog@TExceptionNotificaTY6J18n0Wfo24G1hyGAqTA`

As you can see, the mangled name of the function is 253 chars.  However the decoding breaks down at char 230.

Specifically here:

```
...@TExceptionNotificaTY6J
                      ^^^^
```

Capital letters (other than Q) have no meaning in Borland name mangling.

Is 230 the maximum length a mangled identifier can take?

Given that identifiers are stored in ShortStrings I thought the max was 255.

> Off topic, but for those people who are curious the name unmangles as
>  follows:
>
>  
>  `unit Exceptionnotificationdialog; 
>  .... 
>  function or procedure ReportExceptionNotification
>    (const Str: UnicodeString;
>    InOptions: TExceptionNotificationOptions;
>    out OutOptions: TExceptionsNotificationOptions;
>    ... more parameters? unknown): unknown result type;`

Comment: Is this for "traditional" rtti as in TypInfo.Pas?

Comment: @MartynA: It is what the function is actually exported as in the BPL's PE EXPORTS table (see TDUMP output to confirm).  It has nothing to do with RTTI at all.  And it is clear from this output that there is indeed some kind of truncation occurring. The `Set` data type of the 3rd parameter is truncated. `TY6J18n0Wfo24G1hyGAqTA` is not part of the normal name mangling data.  See [this article](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27758) ([English translation](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fedn.embarcadero.com%2Farticle%2F27758))

Comment: @RemyLebeau:  I wasn't mean to suggest that it was.  I just saw Johan had tagged the q with rtti and he usually has a point.

Comment: @MartynA: This has nothing to do with RTTI, so I have removed that tag.  And also, PE exports are not limited to 256 chars, either.  So I have no clue what is happening here.  Unless there is a bug in the compiler/linker for long export names.

Comment: @RemyLebeau:  Yes, I got the message the first time, thanks.